# Logging different table updates into a CLOB in LOG TABLE Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, sqlplus, plsqldeveloper

I have a **user** table like This.

| id_user | name | statut |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | 1 |
| 2 | bbb | 1 |

and another table **user_log** like this.

| date | nb_rows_affected | details |
| --- | --- | --- |

the log table contains the column details which is a CLOB where I would like to log in details all updates that have been made in the user table.

I'll give you an example, let's say we have the above information in the user table, and we want to update the name and the status of the user aaa to user.name == ccc and his statut to user.statut=2
so I will do it like this

```
update user set statut = 2 and name = 'ccc' where id_user = 1
```

I want that automatically after the update we have the following information in the table of log

```
date = current_date 
nbrow_affected = 1 
details : on table user ; id = 1 , previous value of user.statut = '1' actual value of user.statut = '2'/n
on table user ; id = 1 , previous value of user.name = 'aaa' actual value of user.name = ccc
```

I've been searching it the only way to do it is with triggers on user table update because it can use the new.name and old.name statement,  but I'm stuck on how to implement it properly

How can I do this?

Comment: Any reason you're concatenating this in a clob ? What if you ever have to report on the audit data ? Good luck with that :) If the clob is not a hard requirement, then may I suggest you read this blogpost by Connor McDonald. https://connor-mcdonald.com/2020/08/04/level-up-your-audit-trigger-game/. He has already done the work, just re-use his code.

Comment: that is a really bad idea for a data model. You want all the changes stored in a single column based on date, and rows ?

Comment: yes , that's client requirement if fact it's used to know each day what it the updates that are made by several scripts